# Need I to create a new "instance"?

Tags: jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/cLKm8/1/) is my code :

## HTML

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="example">
        <div class="child">Hello</div>
    </div>    
</div>        

<div id="result"></div>
```

## jQuery

```
htmlSedi="";
sedi(1);
sedi(2)
    
$("#result").append(htmlSedi);    

function sedi(param) {
    var htmlSede = $('#example');
    
    if(param==1)
        htmlSede.find('.child').hide();
    
    htmlSedi=htmlSedi+htmlSede.html();
}
```

the result I aspect is to get at least one "Hello" printed into the div `result`, but in fact it doesnt; I think the problem is on :

```
var htmlSede = $('#example');
```

which point to the same object. So, how can I create a new "instance" of `#example`?

Comment: Sorry, copied a wrong version! Now this is the code I mean...

Comment: I agree with everyone who says that you missed the id selector # in your original posted question

Comment: I updated the question, as you see in my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.clone()` for this.

```
$("#example").clone();
```

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 1):

you missed the ID-selector `#`

also the correct way to fill your `#result` would be:

`htmlSedi.append(htmlSede.html());`

your code should look like this:

```
sedi(1);
sedi(2);

function sedi(param) {
    var htmlSedi = $("#result");
    var htmlSede = $('#example');

    if(param==1)
        htmlSede.find('.child').hide();

    htmlSedi.append(htmlSede.html());
}
```

Also, take a look at:

### Jquery Dom-Manipulation

you can use whichever you want, `.append()`, `.prepend()`, `.after()`, ... whatever suits your needs.

Comment: if you see, I need to append to htmlSedi every htmlSede html code. So I add it as string. Tried htmlSedi.append(), but htmlSedi it is an object, not an jquery object, and it fails...

Comment: yes, but htmlSede in fact it is not in DOM manipulation, it is an object :O

Answer (score 1):

Some errors in the code

```
$("result").append(htmlSedi);
```

should be

```
$("#result").append(htmlSedi);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error

```
 $("result").append(htmlSedi);
```

should be

```
 $("#result").append(htmlSedi);
```

EDIT - you could use [.clone(true);](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
htmlSedi="";
sedi(1);
sedi(2)

$("#result").append(htmlSedi);    

function sedi(param) {
    var htmlSede = $('#example').clone(true);

  if(param==1){
        htmlSede.find('.child').hide();
  }

    htmlSedi=htmlSedi+htmlSede.html();
}
```

pastebin http://jsbin.com/ovejil/edit#preview

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#result").append(htmlSedi); /*you forgot the #*/
```

also you forgot the semicolon on `sedi(2)`

Comment: semicolon after sedi(2) is optional

Comment: but highly recommended - missing semicolons in js can produce hard to detect bugs